# "ModuleNotFoundError" when importing modules inside package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-packaging

I am trying to make my own package so that I can use the files in a different folder. This package contains a few different modules and then the main module that imports all the others inside it. For example:

Folder

```
|- main.py
|- other.py
|- something.py
|- __init__.py
```

Inside the main.py I have the imports:

```
import other
import something
```

and it works just fine when running the file itself; however, I added the __init__.py file and tried to import it into a different folder. The package is recognized, but the main.py gives me the following error:

> Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named
> 'univariate'
>
> File "C:...\stats.py", line 8, in 
> import univariate
>
> File "F:...\testing.py", line 7, in 
> from stats import stats

For clarification, the actual main file is called stats.py. This is my first experience trying to make a package so I might be missing something. Thank you.

Comment: Be sure to read the [Python Packaging Guide](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your imports into *relative imports*

```
import .other
import .something
```

or to change it to *absolute imports* rooted to your project folder

```
import x.y.other
import x.y.something
```

you can read [here](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/) about the imports

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did that with all the imports and now for some reason the line "from stats import stats" is giving me a syntax error

Comment: It was a syntax error, but apparently changing all the imports to stats.moduleName instead of .moduleName is fixing it. It seems most of my errors have to do with mistaking relative paths when I had to use absolute or vice-versa. I should be able to fix it now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you have a module that you're trying to import you don't need the ".py" part.

Having a folder with a **init**.py file (even a blank one) means that a project that contains that folder can import from it.

```
/myproject
| - /mymodule
| - |- stats.py
| - |- other.py
| - |- something.py
| - |- __init__.py
| - main.py
```

then in *main.py* all you need to do is `import mymodule` or `from mymodule import stats`

I always hate to FTFM someone, but here's a link to how to build packages from the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).  But, where this really starts to shine is when you need to package your module so that someone else can run it Digital Ocean has a pretty good tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-package-and-distribute-python-applications).

Comment: thanks for the information, but my issue is not with importing the package itself, but imports inside the package. I had to convert those into relative imports, but now I get a syntax error on the line "from stats import stats" (the package is called stats and has a stats file inside).